# Puppet npm proxy issue

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant, puppet

I use Vagrant + puppet

There is init.pp

```
class { 'apt':
  always_apt_update    => true,
  proxy_host           => 'some.proxy',
  proxy_port           => '222'
}

apt::ppa { 'ppa:chris-lea/node.js':  }

package {
  [
    'nodejs'
  ]:
  ensure => "installed",
  require => Apt::Ppa['ppa:chris-lea/node.js']
}

exec { 'npm_proxy':
  command => 'npm config set proxy http://some.proxy:222',
  path => '/usr/bin/:/bin/',
  require => Package['nodejs'],
}
```

Seems OK. Command has executed successfully. But when I connect to box (vagrant ssh) npm proxy is null...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the npm proxy has been set for `root`.

Puppet runs with `root` credentials, while `vagrant ssh` logs you in as `vagrant` user. So if you want to run the command for `vagrant` you should specify it:

```
exec { 'npm_proxy':
  command => 'npm config set proxy http://some.proxy:222',
  path => '/usr/bin/:/bin/',
  require => Package['nodejs'],
  user => 'vagrant'
}
```

Another option could be to set the npm proxy globally with the `--global` flag.

Comment: Unfortunately user vagrant didn't help... :(

Comment: --global flag helps! Thanks!